# window.criteo_q.push not executing after pageload after checkout

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events, criteo

I moved this code from index body into my html editor for the conversion/thankyou page. This Criteo Javascript should push order details to their database. What is going wrong?

```
<!-- Conversionpage htmlblock in js test -->

<body onload="fireConversion()">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js" async="true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fireConversion() {
 var order_info = JSON.parse(ORDER_JSON).order_rows;
 var basketproducts = [];
  for(var i=0;i<order_info.length;i++) {
    basketproducts.push( { id: order_info[i].product_id, price: order_info[i].price, quantity: order_info[i].count});
  }
 var orderid = '[OrderNumber]';
 window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
 var deviceType = /iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "t" : /Mobile|iP(hone|od)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Silk/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "m" : "d";

 window.criteo_q.push( { event: "setAccount", account: 52999 },  { event: "setSiteType", type: deviceType },  { event: "setEmail", email: "" } , { event: "trackTransaction", id: orderid , item: basketproducts });
</script>
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Vertoshop is not defined
    at return.php:10615
    at return.php:10633

and 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

I think you swapped the last two lines. Try this:

```
<!-- Conversionpage htmlblock in js test -->

<body onload="fireConversion()">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js" async="true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fireConversion() {
    var order_info = JSON.parse(ORDER_JSON).order_rows;
    var basketproducts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < order_info.length; i++) {
        basketproducts.push({ id: order_info[i].product_id, price: order_info[i].price, quantity: order_info[i].count });
    }
    var orderid = '[OrderNumber]';
    window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
    var deviceType = /iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 't' : /Mobile|iP(hone|od)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Silk/.test(
        navigator.userAgent) ? 'm' : 'd';

    window.criteo_q.push({ event: 'setAccount', account: 52999 }, { event: 'setSiteType', type: deviceType },
        { event: 'setEmail', email: '' }, { event: 'trackTransaction', id: orderid, item: basketproducts });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Now it gives 
``` 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

for
``` 
<body onload="fireConversion()">
```

Should I remove the "<>"?

Comment: When I put it into an HTML file it seems to work except that `ORDER_JSON` is undefined. I assume that is sth you left out for simplicity reasons.

Comment: I put this code in the body via back-end html-editor. ORDER_JSON is defined on the page. 

I tried this earlier by putting the code in the index defined with condition only load on conversionpage but the reason i moved it here was because the html variable block "[OrderNumber]" was not loading information in it. The variable basketproducts was loading properly. Now it seems both dont work. 
I looks like the html editor doesnt accept javascript?

Comment: Can I define variable orderid in this window and use it in another window to push to Criteo server?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in the meanwhile.

I put the following code in index body with the condition for the conversion page.

The definition of variable "orderid" is defined by small script in conversion page body html editor.

Code in index body html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js" async="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.body.className == "OrderPage ps-German")
{
  var order_info = JSON.parse(ORDER_JSON).order_rows;
  var basketproducts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < order_info.length; i++) {
     basketproducts.push({ id: order_info[i].product_id, price: order_info[i].price, quantity: order_info[i].count });
  }
  window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
  var deviceType = /iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 't' : /Mobile|iP(hone|od)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Silk/.test(
    navigator.userAgent) ? 'm' : 'd';
  window.criteo_q.push({ event: 'setAccount', account: 59999 }, { event: 'setSiteType', type: deviceType },
    { event: 'setEmail', email: '' }, { event: 'trackTransaction', id: orderid, item: basketproducts });
}
</script>
```

Code in conversion page:

```
<script>
var orderid = '[OrderNumber]';
</script>
```